# Retornar una imagen a partir de datos binarios en JAVA - Servicio Rest

Tags: java, sql-server, jersey2

Buenas tardes.

Tengo la siguiente porción de código que esta dentro de un servicio REST.

```
        String a = "0xFFD8FFE0.........";
        //el valor de a es un dato tipo image de SQL Server
        Blob blob2 = connection.createBlob();
        blob2.setBytes(1, a.getBytes());
        InputStream inputStream2 = blob2.getBinaryStream();

        return Response.ok(inputStream2).build();
```

Resultado obtenido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué has hecho para conseguirlo? Además, este problema pertenecería a tu repositorio de datos, el cual es indistinto si tu aplicación es REST, aplicación web, aplicación de escritorio, etc.

Comment: Esto me funciono

Comment: String image64 = "/9j/";
   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   BufferedImage image = null;
   byte[] imageByte= null, imageData = null;
   Base64.Decoder decoder;
   decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
   imageByte = decoder.decode(image64);
   ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByte);
   try {
    image = ImageIO.read(bis);
    bis.close();
    ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", baos);
    imageData = baos.toByteArray();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

   return Response.ok(imageData).build();